# integrate $3x^3/(1-x^2)^{1/2}$ by trigonometric substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

Please can someone integrate
$$
\int \frac{3x^3}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx
$$
by trigonometric substitution?

Thanks, all.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution

Comment: If you want to avoid trigonometric substitution, $u=1-x^2$ looks promising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x = \sin t$, so that $dx = \cos{t}dt$. Now we have

$$\cos^2 t = 1 - \sin^2 t = 1 - x^2$$

Thus our integral can be re-written as

$$\int \frac{\sin^3 t}{\cos t} \cos{t} dt$$

Comment: @T. Bngers Thank you so much